# Error pickling a `matlab` object in joblib `Parallel` context

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, python-import, joblib

I'm running some Matlab code in parallel from inside a Python context (I know, but that's what's going on), and I'm hitting an import error involving `matlab.double`. The same code works fine in a `multiprocessing.Pool`, so I am having trouble figuring out what the problem is. Here's a minimal reproducing test case.

```py
import matlab
from multiprocessing import Pool
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

# A global object that I would like to be available in the parallel subroutine
x = matlab.double([[0.0]])

def f(i):
    print(i, x)

with Pool(4) as p:
    p.map(f, range(10))
    # This prints 1, [[0.0]]\n2, [[0.0]]\n... as expected

for _ in Parallel(4, backend='multiprocessing')(delayed(f)(i) for i in range(10)):
    pass
# This also prints 1, [[0.0]]\n2, [[0.0]]\n... as expected

# Now run with default `backend='loky'`
for _ in Parallel(4)(delayed(f)(i) for i in range(10)):
    pass
# ^ this crashes.
```

So, the only problematic one is the one using the `'loky'` backend.
The full traceback is:

```
exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7f63b5a57358 state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool>
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 391, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True, timeout=timeout)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 113, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matlab/mlarray.py", line 31, in <module>
    from _internal.mlarray_sequence import _MLArrayMetaClass
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matlab/_internal/mlarray_sequence.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _internal.mlarray_utils import _get_strides, _get_size, \
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matlab/_internal/mlarray_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matlab
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matlab/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from mlarray import double, single, uint8, int8, uint16, \
ImportError: cannot import name 'double'
'''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 625, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 309, in __call__
    self.parallel.dispatch_next()
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 731, in dispatch_next
    if not self.dispatch_one_batch(self._original_iterator):
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 759, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 716, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 510, in apply_async
    future = self._workers.submit(SafeFunction(func))
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/reusable_executor.py", line 151, in submit
    fn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 1022, in submit
    raise self._flags.broken
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 391, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True, timeout=timeout)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 113, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matlab/mlarray.py", line 31, in <module>
    from _internal.mlarray_sequence import _MLArrayMetaClass
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matlab/_internal/mlarray_sequence.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _internal.mlarray_utils import _get_strides, _get_size, \
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matlab/_internal/mlarray_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matlab
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matlab/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from mlarray import double, single, uint8, int8, uint16, \
ImportError: cannot import name 'double'
'''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    for _ in Parallel(4)(delayed(f)(i) for i in range(10)):
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 934, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 833, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 521, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/_base.py", line 625, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 309, in __call__
    self.parallel.dispatch_next()
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 731, in dispatch_next
    if not self.dispatch_one_batch(self._original_iterator):
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 759, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 716, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 510, in apply_async
    future = self._workers.submit(SafeFunction(func))
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/reusable_executor.py", line 151, in submit
    fn, *args, **kwargs)
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 1022, in submit
    raise self._flags.broken
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.
```

Looking at the traceback, it seems like the root cause is an issue importing the `matlab` package in the child process.

It's probably worth noting that this all runs just fine if instead I had defined `x = np.array([[0.0]])` (after importing `numpy as np`). And of course the main process has no problem with any `matlab` imports, so I am not sure why the child process would.

I'm not sure if this error has anything in particular to do with the `matlab` package, or if it's something to do with global variables and `cloudpickle` or `loky`. In my application it would help to stick with `loky`, so I'd appreciate any insight!

I should also note that I'm using the official Matlab engine for Python: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html. I suppose that might make it hard for others to try out the test cases, so I wish I could reproduce this error with a type other than `matlab.double`, but I haven't found another yet.

Digging around more, I've noticed that the process of importing the `matlab` package is more circular than I would expect, and I'm speculating that this could be part of the problem? The issue is that when `import matlab` is run by `loky`'s `_ForkingPickler`, first some file `matlab/mlarray.py` is imported, which imports some other files, one of which contains `import matlab`, and this causes `matlab/__init__.py` to be run, which internally has `from mlarray import double, single, uint8, ...` which is the line that causes the crash.

Could this circularity be the issue? If so, why can I import this module in the main process but not in the `loky` backend?

Comment: You are probably correct. `import matlab` should be first run before anything. Try the argument [`initializer`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) in `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`. Use `def initializer(): import matlab` to verify the hypotheses.

Comment: Seem that [there is no simple way to specify the initializer](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/381) without hacking joblib.

Comment: These are good tips, didn't know about the initializer for `Pool`. Too bad joblib doesn't have it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is caused by **incorrect loading order** of global objects in the child processes. It can be seen clearly in the traceback 
`_ForkingPickler.loads(res) -> ... -> import matlab -> from mlarray import ...`
that `matlab` is not yet imported when the global variable `x` is loaded by `cloudpickle`.

`joblib` with `loky` seems to treat modules as normal global objects and send them dynamically to the child processes. joblib doesn't record the order in which those objects/modules were defined. Therefore they are loaded (initialized) in a random order in the child processes.

A simple workaround is to manually pickle the matlab object and load it after importing matlab inside your function.

```
import matlab
import pickle

px = pickle.dumps(matlab.double([[0.0]]))

def f(i):
    import matlab
    x=pickle.loads(px)
    print(i, x)
```

Of course you can also use the [joblib.dumps](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.dump.html) and `loads` to serialize the objects.

### Use initializer

Thanks to the suggestion of @Aaron, you can also use an `initializer` ([for loky](https://loky.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/reuseable_executor.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-reuseable-executor-py)) to import Matlab before loading `x`.

[Currently there's no simple API to specify `initializer`](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/381). So I wrote a simple function:

```
def with_initializer(self, f_init):
    # Overwrite initializer hook in the Loky ProcessPoolExecutor
    # https://github.com/tomMoral/loky/blob/f4739e123acb711781e46581d5ed31ed8201c7a9/loky/process_executor.py#L850
    hasattr(self._backend, '_workers') or self.__enter__()
    origin_init = self._backend._workers._initializer
    def new_init():
        origin_init()
        f_init()
    self._backend._workers._initializer = new_init if callable(origin_init) else f_init
    return self
```

It is a little bit hacky but works well with the current version of joblib and loky.
Then you can use it like:

```
import matlab
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

x = matlab.double([[0.0]])

def f(i):
    print(i, x)

def _init_matlab():
    import matlab

with Parallel(4) as p:
    for _ in with_initializer(p, _init_matlab)(delayed(f)(i) for i in range(10)):
        pass
```

I hope the developers of joblib will add `initializer` argument to the constructor of `Parallel` in the future.